# jQuery File Upload, get and edit Data which is saved in DB

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-file-upload

**Edited**

With the [jQuery File Upload Documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) I am able to save Data with the pictures in MySQL DB
(see pic 1+2)

Now where I'm stuck is how to retrieve the Data back. After the Upload I would like to show the pics with the Data from DB but there is nothing I can find how to do that.

If anyone knows how to edit the json appending the DB data OR just how I can var_dump it just to push me in the right direction that would be awesome! I can not find where the json gets created. The json now looks like this:

```
{"files":[{
    "name"         : "02 (1).jpg",
    "size"         : 12508,
    "type"         : "image\/jpeg",
    "url"          : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/files\/02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl" : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "deleteUrl"    : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/?file=02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "deleteType"   : "DELETE"
}]}
```

and I would like to make it like:

```
{"files":[{
    "name"         : "02 (1).jpg",
    "size"         : 12508,
    "type"         : "image\/jpeg",
    "url"          : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/files\/02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl" : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "deleteUrl"    : "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/server\/php\/?file=02%20%281%29.jpg",
    "deleteType"   : "DELETE",
    "titleDB"      : "Title1",
    "textDB"       : "Lorem ipsum dolor...."
}]}
```

I tried (like rAjA explained) and changed the following

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$response_enc = $this->upload_handler->initialize();
```

But than I get an error saying "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data" and I googeld for that and I found information but there is nothing which helped me.

Can anyone help me on this one or knows where I can find the Information? Thank you!

[image: pic][image: pic2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the basic idea of editing the json response from uploadhandler library,

**EDITED:**

In your uploadhandler.php library and change this line so that it will return the response,

`public function post($print_response = true)` to `public function post($print_response = false)`

`public function get($print_response = true)` to `public function get($print_response = false)`

`protected function initialize()` to `public function initialize()`

**EDITED:** change this too `function __construct($options = null, $initialize = false, $error_messages = null)`

and in

```
function initialize()
//
            case 'POST':
                return $this->post(); //Change this line like here
                break;
////
            case 'GET':
                return $this->get(); //Change this line like here
                break;
//
```

Then in the function where you calling the library get the response back,

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$response = $upload_handler>initialize();

print_r($response); //Dump the response here and check    

$custom_arr = //Save all your custom variables here (DB insert id, Text etc)
//Sample format of custom_arr
//$custom_arr['insert_id']  = $mysql_primary_key_id;
//$custom_arr['txt']  = $user_custom_text_field;
//

$response['custom_data'] = $custom_arr;

echo json_encode($response);
```

In your front end you can use the `fileuploaddone` callback to get the data and play with it.

Comment: as soon as I have this $response_enc = $this->upload_handler->initialize(); I get a error (JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data) any idea why?   how should the $custom_arr (variables) be looking like?

Comment: still the same error caused by this line $response_enc = $this->upload_handler->initialize(); also need a little more information how to use fileuploaddone (there is not much in the docs) should I update my question?

Comment: did you make the chang in the function initialize as I mentioned?  Can show the error you got?

Comment: I just saw your edit. Can you confirm that you have made the changes in your code like my edited code? Because if you removed `json_decode` line you shouldn't get the `JSON.parse: unexpected` error

Comment: If you have successfully edited the Json response, we can focus on handling it in front end code using `fileuploaddone`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37009/discussion-between-caramba-and-raja)